# How to initialize Serilog in Windows Service?

Tags: .net, initialization, windows-services, serilog

I have the following issue.I want to be able to use `Serilog` inside a windows service and i do not know where it should be initilized:

Currently i initialize it in my `Main`:

```
using Serilog;

public static void RunService() {
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
      .WriteTo.RollingFile([some path])
      .CreateLogger();

    MyService daemon = new MyService();
    Log.Information("Service initialized")

    ServiceBase[] services;
    services = new ServiceBase[] {
        service
    };
    Log.Information("Before running the service");
    ServiceBase.Run(services);
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
   RunService();
}
```

**Service**

```
public class MyService:ServiceBase{
   protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription) {
    Log.Information("session changed");
   } 
   protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {
     Log.Information("Started service");
   }
}
```

So in order to use `Serilog` both in the `Main` that runs the collection of services and inside the target service how is it supposed to be done?

Comment: What's the actual problem? The code can work as is, but 'work' depends on what you expect. Also the `RollingFile` sink is deprecated; you should use `.File` for new code.

Comment: So i do not need to initiaize the logger inside the service too.That was my question.I was afraid of unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common practice is to do what you're doing - i.e. Initialize logging at the very beginning and store the logger in `Log.Logger` - and then, within your service, get a hold of a context logger, `Log.ForContext<T>`. E.g.

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
using Serilog;

namespace WindowsServiceHost
{
    public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger _log = Log.ForContext<MyService>();

        public MyService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            _log.Information("Service starting...");
            // ...

            _log.Information("Service started.");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            _log.Information("Service stopping...");
            // ...

            _log.Information("Service stopped.");
        }
    }
}
```

This makes it very simple to get access to Serilog's logger, and has the added benefit of giving you [contextual information](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Writing-Log-Events#source-contexts) about where the log messages are coming from, which is useful.

You might be interested in reading this: [Context and correlation – structured logging concepts in .NET (5)](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/08/context-and-correlation-structured-logging-concepts-in-net-5/)

---

Also, don't forget to call `Log.CloseAndFlush()` before your service stops, to make sure any buffered messages are written to the sink(s).

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.File(@"C:\SomePath\MyApp.log")
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new MyService(),
            };

            ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush(); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about this in the documentation: [Lifecycle of Loggers](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Lifecycle-of-Loggers)

Comment: I prefer this approach since i  am able to get the context wihtout injecting the logger  in all constructors if i have a deep hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, is by injecting an `ILogger` instance in the constructor of your Windows Service, which you pass from the `Main` method.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.File(@"C:\SomePath\MyApp.log")
            .CreateLogger();

        var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new MyService(Log.Logger), // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        };

        ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
    }
}
```

And in your Windows Service, you add a constructor that takes an `ILogger` instance. You still need to keep a constructor that doesn't take any arguments, so that you still open the visual designer within Visual Studio:

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    private readonly ILogger _log;

    public MyService()
        : this(Log.Logger)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MyService(ILogger logger) // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        _log = logger.ForContext<MyService>();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _log.Information("Service starting...");
        // ...

        _log.Information("Service started.");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _log.Information("Service stopping...");
        // ...

        _log.Information("Service stopped.");
    }
}
```